# Cannot Implement or extend - java

Tags: java, inheritance, implements

I have a class `C` with lots of members(say 10 members) + members that are only in C

I have two more classes `A` and `B` which has exactly those above mentioned 10 members. **(A and B each does not have those 10 members. Those 10 members are distributed among A and B and A and B has few other fields)**

```
class C {
    private int member1;
    private String member2;
    private String member3;
    private float member4;
    ...
    private String member10;

    private member11_only_in_C;
    private member12_only_in_C;
    ...
}



class A {
    private String memeber10;
    private float member4;
    private double member6;
    ....
}
class B {
     private int memeber1;
     private String memeber2;
     private String member7;
     ....
 }
```

So when I have `cObject` I need to set the values of all members in `A` and `B` like

```
aObject.setMember10(cObject.getMember10());
bObject.setMember1(cObject.getMember1());
... and so on for all 10 members
```

This looks bad(long and in future If i add more members to C,A,B I need to write setters for them).  So what I thought was If I have class C `extend or implement A and B` I can `cast` it like

```
 A aObject = (A)cObject;
 B bObject = (B)cObject;
```

But the problems are

1. Java does not allow multiple inheritance
2. I cannot make `A` and `B` as interfaces because I need to set their values. (If I make them as interfaces, their members would become `final`, which means that I cannot change their values)
3. I cannot extend one class and implement other. (I then cannot set values of members of the interface)

What can I do now?

Thanks..

Comment: You've said the similarities between `A`, `B` and `C` (they all have the same fields), but what are the differences? Why do you need 3 classes rather than 1?

Comment: A and B have members that are in C. C can have any other fields.

Comment: This still reeks of bad code design. You should have a base class with only common members, and use aggregation and inheritance (or some other non-class-based methodology) to incorporate the additional members into A, B, and C.

Comment: As @ShotgunNinja stated, proper design would be something like this: if C is a dump truck, B might be a truck, and A might be a motor vehicle, so A is the super class of B and B is the super class of C. There's nothing to prevent a class D, say a car from also having A as it's super class. Your casting code will still work just fine.

Comment: If you can't change the hierarchy of A, B, and C, then you should consider encapsulation of A and B inside of C, and route C's accessors to use A or B to provide the information needed. This can be sloppy and excessive, however, and may detract from the ability of users to understand where their information is coming from.

Comment: I agree that design is a bit sloppy. But when I have an object of class C, I need to set all values of A and B and also compute values of some fields in A and B based on certain values of fields of C

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it you have two classes `A` and `B`, both with a number of fields, and you want to create a third class `C` with all the fields of `A` and `B`.

As you point out you can't do this with inheritance in Java because multiple inheritance of state is not supported.

You can do something similar using composition instead.

```
public final class C {

    private final A a;
    private final B b;

    public C(A a, B b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

    ...

    void setMember7(String s) {
        b.setMember7(s);
    }

    String getMember7() {
        return b.getMember7();
    }

    ...
}
```

I'm not sure if this is a good idea or what you need though. We would need more information about your use-case.

**EDIT**

If `A` and `B` have fields that are not in `C` you could make a class `A2` with all the fields common to `A` and `C` and a class `B2` with all the fields common to `B` and `C`, like this:

```
public final class A {

    private final A2 a2;
    // other fields

    public A(A2 a2) { 
        this.a2 = a2;
    }
}

public final class B {

    private final B2 b2;
    // other fields

    public B(B2 b2) {
        this.b2 = b2;
    }
}

public final class C {

    private final A2 a2 = new A2();
    private final B2 b2 = new B2();

    ...

    public void setMember7(String s) {
        b2.setMember7(s);
    }

    public String getMember7() {
        return b2.getMember7();
    }

    ...

    public A getA() {
        return new A(a2);
    }

    public B getB() {
        return new B(b2);
    } 
}
```

Comment: I have all three class to begin with. When I have an object of class C I need to populate the fields of A and B

Comment: This does not solve my problem. Still all members have to be set one by one

Comment: @Ashwin I've changed my answer. I don't know if this is any better. You can avoid setting fields one by one by bundling fields up into a class.

Comment: @Ashwin You don't. Whatever methods you currently have for `C` don't need to change - the only difference is that they change fields of `A2` and `B2` rather than fields of `C` directly. If you don't want to write setters, you can simply make the fields of `A2` and `B2` package private (not usually a good idea but it works). If you don't want to use composition, and you  don't want to transfer the fields individually, you would have to resort to reflection - read through the fields of `A` in a loop and set the values according to values of a `C` instance, but that would be hideous.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what you want but i think what you need can be accomplished  in the constructor

```
Class A{
 private member1;
 private member10;
 Class A(){
 }
 Class A(C cObject){
  member1 = cObject.getMember1();
  //the rest of member varaibles you want to set
  member10 = cObject.getMember10();
  }
}
Class B{
 private member1;
 private member10;
 Class B(){
 }
 Class B(C cObject){
  member1 = cObject.getMember1();
  //the rest of member varaibles you want to set
  member10 = cObject.getMember10();
  }
}
```

to use it :-

```
 B objectB = new B(objectC);
 A objectB = new A(objectC);
```

Comment: This does not solve my problem. Still all members have to be set one by one